# Amdroid drop down menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, xamarin.android

I am looking for a drop down menu similar to this for my Droid app, i would prefer to not home brew it if something already exists:

[image]

Comment: Search *Android PopupWindow*

Answer (score 0):

Closet thing i know of is:

http://www.pavanh.com/2013/05/android-popup-menu-example.html

then perhaps find a way to use a custom 9 patch to make your bubble type effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should be styled as a Dialog.

You need to update your AndroidManifest.xml, add :

```
<activity 
    android:name="package.activity" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

And then customize your theme to approach your bubble idea...

**Edit**: Muhammad has useful answer too, it's more like a popup window that you need, see

http://androidituts.com/android-popup-window-tutorial-2/